# Regex Matching for Bash

Tags: regex, bash

I have potential inputs that will come in from a `read -e -p` command in a bash script. For example, the user would type `L50CA`. Some other possibilites that the user could type in are: `K117CB`, `K46CE2`, or `V9CE1`.

I need to break up what was read in. I read in like this:

```
read -e -p "What first atom? " sel1
```

then I would like to make an array like this (but this will not separate):

```
arr1=($sel1)
```

But I need to separate the array so that

`${arr1[0]}` is equal to L
`${arr1[1]}` is equal to 50
and `${arr1[2]}` is equal to CA

This separation has to work with the other possible user input formats like the ones listed above. Regex seems to be the way to do this. I can isolate the first two matches of the input with the following regular expressions: `^\D` and `\d*(?=\w)`

I need help matching the third component and implementing it into an array. Alternatively, it is fine to to break up the user input into three new variables. Or we can place a space between each of the matches so `L50CA` is converted to `L 50 CA` because then `arr1=($sel1)` will work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do `K46CE2` split into? `K`, `46`, `CE2`? Or `K`, `46`, `CE`, `2`?

Comment: It would split into K 46 CE2. It is fine if they come out separate like they did with jm66's answer because it is trivial to just combine the 3rd and 4th entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

```
for sel in L50CA K117CB K46CE2 V9CE1
do
        arr=($(sed 's/\([0-9][0-9]*\)/ \1 /g'<<<"$sel"))
        echo "${arr[@]}"
done
```

prints

```
L 50 CA
K 117 CB
K 46 CE 2
V 9 CE 1
```

Comment: Awesome thanks so much. All I needed to do here is combine `${arr[2]}${arr[3]}`. Great solution.

Answer (score 2):

Bash only solution:

```
for sel in L50CA K117CB K46CE2 V9CE1; do
    [[ "$sel" =~ "^(\w)([0-9]+)(.*)" ]]
    printf '%s - ' "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"
    printf \\n;
done
```

Answer (score 1):

In bash using [string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html):

```
 ~$ sel1=L50CA
 ~$ part1=$(expr match $sel1 "\([A-Z]\+\).*")
 ~$ part2=$(expr match $sel1 "[A-Z]*\([0-9]\+\).*")
 ~$ part3=$(expr match $sel1 "[A-Z]*[0-9]*\([A-Z]*\)")
 ~$ echo $part{1,2,3}
 L 50 CA
 ~$ arr=($part{1,2,3})
 ~$ echo ${arr[@]}
 L 50 CA
```

Comment: I did not even know string manipulation existed in bash...how elegant. Thanks for the great solution.

Comment: That's not `bash` that's `expr`.

Comment: @EtanReisner http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expr shows it's incorporated into the shell as a built-in command. (Here `type expr` gives `expr is /usr/bin/expr` though.)

Comment: Evaluating expressions is a builtin. `expr` is not. `expr` existed before the shell could do that sort of thing as I understand it (which would seem to be what wikipedia was trying to state there).